# reading from a database using WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, podscms

I am very new to WordPress, I have very little knowledge with PHP.
I read about PODS and I know how to create one and use pages / templates to display data.

The issue I am havingis, the PODS I was creating use static data entered via the WP dashboard, what I want is to read data from a database, I am using MySql (same DB that wordpress is using). is there a way to use PODS and read the data from the DB, or wordpress has a better way to handle data coming from the DB ?

Thanks

Comment: site is down, what exactly does it do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should Look into the $wpdb variable (and class)
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Do remember to declare it a global:

```
<?php global $wpdb; ?>
```

I am however not sure what you want.
I advise staying close to wordpress.
If you want to create your own custom post types without using code use [moretypes](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-types/)

Answer (score 6):

Usual way to read from database in WordPress is the following:

1. get global variable $wpdb

   ```
   global $wpdb
   ```
2. prepare the output and SQL command

   ```
   $output = "";
   $sql = "SELECT ".$wpdb->prefix."posts.post_title,
   ".$wpdb->prefix."posts.post_name FROM ".
   $wpdb->prefix."posts WHERE ".$wpdb->prefix.
   "posts.post_status='publish' AND ".$wpdb->prefix.
   "posts.post_parent=0 AND ".$wpdb->prefix.
   "posts.post_type='sometype'";
   ```
3. method get_results() retrieves values from db

   ```
   $posts = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
   $output .= '';
   foreach ($posts as $post) {
   $output .= 'post_name).
   '">'.strip_tags($post->post_title).'';
   }
   $output .= '';
   echo $output;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress CSM has a very good class to work with db, i think the better bet on this is learn how db connects and get data from mysql